# Vagrant sync folder not working after OSX Mavericks upgrade

Tags: macos, virtualbox, vagrant, puppet, osx-mavericks

I am facing a particular issue with Vagrant 1.3.5 on Virtualbox 4.3.4, `vagrant up` stalls during mounting sync (share) folder.

The sequence of output is as following:

```
[default] Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
[default] Creating shared folders metadata...
[default] Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
[default] Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
[default] Forwarding ports...
[default] -- 22 => 2222 (adapter 1)
[default] Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
[default] Booting VM...
GuestAdditions 4.3.2 running --- OK.
[default] Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
[default] Machine booted and ready!
[default] Setting hostname...
[default] Configuring and enabling network interfaces...
[default] Mounting shared folders...
[default] -- /vagrant
[default] -- /tmp/vagrant-puppet/manifests
```

output stops after the last line, normally it will goes on to mount NFS folder.

**The interesting part is**: if I `vagrant destroy` the vm and `vagrant up` again, it's guaranteed to work the first time, but any `up` or `reload` beyond that will face the same issue again.

Since this is my dev environment, i have tried quite a few solutions, but so far none fixes my particular problem, you can see my investigation at: https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/2564

I would appreciate some suggestion on how to debug and resolve it.

---

**Update**:

it seems Vagrant 1.2.x with Virtualbox 4.2.x does work on OSX Mavericks, which leads me to think my vagrantfile is wrong (or it triggers some bug in vagrant 1.3), but I can't spot it myself, so here is the change i made:

my old 1.2 config

```
if Vagrant::Util::Platform.windows?
    config.vm.synced_folder "www", "/var/www", :extra => "dmode=777,fmode=777", :owner => "vagrant", :group => "vagrant"
else
    config.vm.synced_folder "www", "/var/www", :extra => "dmode=777,fmode=777", :nfs => true
end
```

vs 1.3 config

```
if Vagrant::Util::Platform.windows?
    config.vm.synced_folder "www", "/var/www", :mount_options => ["dmode=777","fmode=777"], :owner => "vagrant", :group => "vagrant"
else
    config.vm.synced_folder "www", "/var/www", :nfs => { :mount_options => ["dmode=777","fmode=777"] }
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

turns out it's indeed a bug: https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/2564, should be fixed in future release.